# how to open authentification popup or modal in Angular 2

Tags: authentication, typescript, angular, modal-dialog

I am trying to code a **login component** for my application in **Angular 2** version rc-1. But I did not find **how to open my modal** without a button action.

When I load my app, I check if the user is logged or not (with the localStorage) : if he is not logged the login modal had to be openned.

So open/close modal **is conditionned by a boolean parameter** and not a action button.

Do you know how can I open a login modal without a button action ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is it the bootstrap modal component?

Comment: You can use `ngIf` on the modal div to show/hide the entire div.

Comment: I use bootstrap modal and primeng modal but both don't satisfy my needs. My Login component is a independant component so I imported it in App component ! I tried to use `ngIf` but doesn't work besides the parameter is as `true` ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a component that holds your modal.

```
export class YourModalComponent {
  constructor () {}

  public open(): void {
     //show modal
  }
}
```

And then you have a component that checks the local storage and has `YourModalComponent` as a children. If the user is logged in you just call `modal.open()`.

```
export class YourParentComponent {
  @ViewChild(YourModalComponent)
  public yourModal : YourModalComponent;

  constructor() {}

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    //check if user is logged in
    if(!userIsLoggedIn) {
       this.yourModal.open();
    }

  }
}
```

You can also have the `div` displaying with `ngIf` so the `YourModalComponent` is only displayed if it meets the condition.

Comment: I use this solution. We are near the goal but I have this exception : `EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined`! If I remove the condition on `userIsLoggedIn`, it is work : the modal is open !

Comment: how are you checking if the user is logged in?

Comment: `export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


    @ViewChild(LoginComponent) modal: LoginComponent;
    
    isLoggedIn: boolean = false;
    
    constructor(private auth : AuthentificationService) {
      this.isLoggedIn = this.auth.isLoggedin();
      console.log(this);
    }
    
    
    public ngOnInit(): void {
        //check if user is logged in
        if(!this.isLoggedIn) {
            this.open();           
       }
    }
    
    
    close() {
        this.modal.close();
    }

    open() {
        this.modal.open();
    }
    
}`

Comment: Yes ! Got it ! I change ngOnit to ngAfterViewInit and it's working now  ! Thanks